# Call system call to node from C++?

Tags: c++, node.js, c++11, system-calls

From C++, is there a way to do a system call to run `node process-file.js ./target_folder/`?

The standard call from my C++ project is:

`node ../folderA/subfolder/process-file.js firstArgument ./target_folder/outputFile.txt`

Comment: The first Google hit for "c++ system call" is: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/ - and that pretty much explains it, complete with example and everything.

Comment: I jumped the gun, that is the first thing I tried but noticed that my compiler (through my IDE) warns that `system` is deprecated ... should have phrased my question with this bit first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  const char *programname = "/usr/local/bin/node";

  const char **nargv = new const char* [5];//extra room for program name and sentinel
  nargv [0] = programname; // by convention is program name
  nargv [1] = "/folder/convert-json.js";   // arg 1 to node
  nargv [2] = "/folder/723edc747c39.json"; // arg 2
  nargv [3] = "/tmp/data.json"; // arg 3
  nargv [4] = NULL;  // end of arguments sentinel is NULL

  pid_t pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0) /* child */ {
    if (execv(programname, (char **)nargv) == -1) {
      /* Handle error */
      std::cout << "!! an error in calling node\n";
    }
    _exit(1);  /* in case execv() fails */
  }
```

I built on yours (@josh-olson). This code works hope it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

You may use fork() instead of system() like shown:

```
char *filename = /* something */;

pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) /* child */ {
  if (execve(filename, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
    /* Handle error */
  }
  _exit(1);  /* in case execve() fails */
}
```

[Do not call system()](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=87152177)

Comment: Yes, you are right about `system()`. Your suggestion does not work but is close.